# How to solve a differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the system $$\frac{d^4x}{dt}+4x=0,\quad\frac{d^3x}{dt}+x=0.$$ However, I don't know of any method of tackling such a problem. Can anyone please provide a route to a solution? Please say what method are needed to be applied to solve such a problem.

Comment: Maybe a textbook would be useful?

Comment: If you're trying to solve them together,  just add the two equations together and get a $x^{(4)}+x^{(3)}+5x=0$,  then solve via the methods below

Comment: @Alan: If you add the linear equations $x+y=3$ and $x-y=1$, you get $x=2$. Are its solutions all solutions of the original system? This is very misleading.

Comment: True, you have to go back and ensure that the solutions found also solve the individual ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we differentiate the second equation once and subtract from the first, we obtain $dx/dt = 4x$, so $x=Ce^{4t}$. Only for the constant $0$ do we get a solution of each of the original equations.

We can see this from a slightly more complicated perspective. As @Ian's solution points out, the general solution must be a linear combination of functions of the form $e^{\lambda t}$, where $\lambda^4+4=0$. But it must *simultaneously* be a linear combination of functions of the form $e^{\mu t}$, where $\mu^3+1=0$. There can be no such linear combinations, other than $0$.

Answer (score 1):

I see now that this is a system of equations.

Differentiating the second equation $x'''' + x' = 0$. Together with the first equation $x'''' + 4x = 0$, we have $x' = 4x$, or $x(t) = Ae^{4t}$.

But substituting that form of $x$ back into either equation, we see $A = 0$.

Hence the only solution to the system is the trivial solution, $x(t) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

You have a linear ordinary differential equation with constant coefficients. Any such problem can, at least in principle, be solved by the use of the characteristic polynomial. (In practice finding the roots may be difficult in certain cases.)

For example, in your first problem, the characteristic polynomial is $p(\lambda)=\lambda^4+4$. This has roots $\lambda_j=4^{1/4} e^{i \pi/4 + j \pi/2}$ for $j=0,\dots,3$. Hence the general solution to the homogeneous problem is $x(t)=\sum_{j=0}^3 c_j e^{\lambda_j t}$, for (complex) constants $c_0,\dots,c_3$.

Comment: @SimonS Thanks, I will correct it.

Comment: ...Now that mistake was just mindless on my part. Corrected!